# Freezing French baguette dough

Tags: baking, bread, freezing

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m08i8oXpFB0), the author makes 4 French baguettes. That is probably 2 more baguettes than I can eat before they get stale.

Recipe (transcribed from the video):

Ingredients:

- Bread flour, 700 g
- Instant dried yeast, 0.5 tsp
- Kosher salt, 1.5 tsp
- Cool tap water, 520 g

Steps:

1. Whisk 1st 3 ingredients together.
2. Add water and mix with the handle of a wooden spoon.
3. Cover the bowl with clear wrap and rest for 45 minutes at room temperature.
4. Repeat 4 times:

   - Turn onto a flat surface, wet your hands, and fold from each side to center, then use a dough scraper to put the dough back into the bowl (2:30 in the video).
   - Cover the bowl with clear wrap and rest for 45 minutes at room temperature.
5. Sprinkle the work surface with bench flour and turn out the dough.
6. Divide the dough into 4 equal pieces (each about 310 g).
7. Shape the baguettes (6:30).
8. Leaving the baguettes on the work surface, cover them with lightly oiled clear wrap.
9. Let them rest for 15 minutes.
10. Prepare a well floured bakers couche (7:20).
11. Form the baguettes (7:50), dust lightly, and transfer to the couche.
12. Cover with a tea towel and let them rise for 20 minutes, then a further 12 minutes while the oven preheats to 200°C/400°F.
13. Place a pan of boiling water in the bottom of the oven.
14. Transfer each baguette to a lightly oiled baking sheet using a peel or cardboard covered in aluminum foil (10:45).
15. Spray the baguettes lightly with water
16. Score the baguettes with a razor blade or very sharp knife (11:20).
17. Place the baking sheet(s) in the oven and spray a little water over them to moisten the crust.
18. Bake for 8 minutes, then turn the baking sheet(s) 180° for more even baking, releasing the steam from the oven carefully.
19. Transfer the baguettes to a cooling rack.

Note that I have not tried this recipe yet, but plan to very soon.

How late in the process can I freeze the dough? I assume that when I want to eat it later, I can just thaw the dough and continue the process from that point.

Comment: I can't say on this specific recipe, but I typically do it before it's risen too much.  Say, a slow rise in the fridge, work the dough, then divide & freeze half.  (if you can, in something like a gallon zip-top bag, so it's relatively thin, and will freeze & thaw faster)

Comment: I was actually thinking of using my vacuum sealer (for sous vide) to freeze the dough to prevent freezer burn, but I have to be careful to not crush the dough.

Comment: Hello Ralph, please see the older question I used as a duplicate target. It also has three more "linked" questions in the right side bar. If your question is different from those, please edit yours to make clear what is different in your case and cast a reopening vote or flag.